# What is the chronological order of Adi Shankaracharya's compositions?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya

It is said that Adi Shankara was 8 years old when he first recited Nirvana Shatakam,
I'd like to know the sequence for his other works.

Comment: To be honest, we don't even know what are genuinely the compositions of Shri Adi Shankaracharya.

Comment: List of Compositions of Sri. Shankara is avail. in the website of Kanchi mutt. https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/Adi%20Sankara's%20works.html          Dig Vijaya texts may consulted for chronological order

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.